# MPLS L3 VPNs and F5 Route Domains

Tags: bgp, nat, juniper-junos, mpls-vpn, f5

I realize the F5 community might be the right place for this question, but this concerns routing design as opposed to an ADC design. We are planning to use F5's CGNAT module for NAT'ing our campus traffic. These will be two devices in an inter-site geo-redundant configuration. The F5's are not inline with our PE routers and are more like in a router-on-a-stick setup. We have a BGP/MPLS IP VPN backbone and would like to utilize that by attracting traffic from (say) VRF-A to NAT-1 device and VRF-B to NAT-2 device. F5's routing module ZebOS has no MPLS capabilities, instead they use something similar called Route Domains (https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/tmos-ip-routing-administration-11-2-0/2.html), using route-domain ids to seperate VRFs as opposed to route-distinguishers in MPLS VPNs.

I'd would like to know if the following is possible:

Assuming we have two VRFs (VRF-A and VRF-B) in our backbone, create two route domains (RD-A and RD-B) on each F5. Advertise a default from each route domain for the corresponding VRF on the PE router. Configure BGP local-pref for the default route higher for VRF-A that VRF-B on one PE router and the opposite on the other PE, and advertise the modified defaults across the rest of the backbone. I believe this way we can attract traffic for one VRF to a particular NAT device and the other VRF to the other NAT device.

The question is how do we associate route domains on F5 to the VRFs on our PE routers, so that the default from one route domain ends up only in one of the VRFs. Is this something that can be done on the F5 or needs to be done on the PE routers, or something that will happen automatically as a part of the MPLS backbone when the defaults are advertised from the F5.

Would really appreciate any inputs on the above or other design recommendations.

TIA !

Comment: Could you assign a router domain to a VLAN, then put that VLAN  interface into a VRF?

Comment: Route-domains are vrf's, just different vendor terminology.

Comment: Thank you @Ron. Apologize for the delayed response. Yes, we can assign route-domain to a vlan and assign that vlan interface to a VRF on the PE.

Comment: Yes @cpt_fink, they are essentially the same thing. Really hope that at some point in the future ZebOS has MPLS capabilities. Its a standard and gives us the option of making the platform/devices a part of the backbone.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the question... if you know that route-domain = vrf, then what are you trying to solve?  Is there a routing protocol issue between the F5 and your next-hop gateway?

Comment: @cpt_fink apologize for that, i should have been more clear. I wanted to know about how route-domains worked in conjunction with vrfs on a PE. But after going through some vendor docs and Ron's response, it all makes sense now. Not a routing protocol issue per say, but how might one make route-domains on f5 work with vrfs on a PE.